# HTTP requests between two docker services works fine but I don't know why

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, docker-compose

I have two nodejs services:

- `/server` => NodeJS API built using NestJS. Exposes one `GET` route: `/` that return "Hello World"
- `/client` => ReactJS application that fetches data("Hello World") from the `server` api.

---

This is my project structure:

```
.
├── client
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── package-lock.json
│   ├── public
│   │   ├── favicon.ico
│   │   ├── index.html
│   │   ├── logo192.png
│   │   ├── logo512.png
│   │   ├── manifest.json
│   │   └── robots.txt
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── App.css
│   │   ├── App.test.tsx
│   │   ├── App.tsx
│   │   ├── index.css
│   │   ├── index.tsx
│   │   ├── logo.svg
│   │   ├── react-app-env.d.ts
│   │   ├── serviceWorker.ts
│   │   └── setupTests.ts
│   ├── tsconfig.json
│   └── yarn.lock
├── docker-compose.yml
└── server
    ├── dist
    │   ├── app.controller.d.ts
    │   ├── app.controller.js
    │   ├── app.controller.js.map
    │   ├── app.module.d.ts
    │   ├── app.module.js
    │   ├── app.module.js.map
    │   ├── app.service.d.ts
    │   ├── app.service.js
    │   ├── app.service.js.map
    │   ├── main.d.ts
    │   ├── main.js
    │   ├── main.js.map
    │   └── tsconfig.build.tsbuildinfo
    ├── Dockerfile
    ├── nest-cli.json
    ├── package.json
    ├── package-lock.json
    ├── README.md
    ├── src
    │   ├── app.controller.spec.ts
    │   ├── app.controller.ts
    │   ├── app.module.ts
    │   ├── app.service.ts
    │   └── main.ts
    ├── test
    │   ├── app.e2e-spec.ts
    │   └── jest-e2e.json
    ├── tsconfig.build.json
    └── tsconfig.json
```

---

`server/Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:latest

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json .
COPY package-lock.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "run", "start:dev"]
```

---

`client/Dockerfile`

```
# pull official base image
FROM node:13.12.0-alpine

# set working directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install app dependencies
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm install react-scripts@3.4.1 -g --silent

# add app
COPY . ./

# start app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

---

`docker-compose.yml`

```yml
version: "3.8"
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ''
      POSTGRES_DB: the-notebook-dev-db
  server:
    build: ./server
    volumes:
      - ./server:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - '4000:4000'
    depends_on:
      - postgres
  client:
    tty: true
    build: ./client
    volumes:
      - ./client:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    depends_on:
      - server
```

Everything works as expected. Client makes a GET request to `http://localhost:4000`, receives the "Hello World" message. However, shouldn't `localhost`, when used by the client container, point to the client container itself? How is this setup working and why am I not able to use `http://service:4000` instead of `http://localhost:4000`?

Comment: Is `client` a React application?  Is that GET request being made from the browser, or code that's running natively in the container?

Comment: @DavidMaze The client IS a ReactJS application which is making a get request to the api(server) from host browser

Comment: The browser isn't in Docker, and the React application can't use any of the Docker networking features.  You need to use the host name of the server and the published port number in this context (it can be `localhost` only if you're running the browser from the same host/VM that's running the container).